# The fileinfo PHP extension is not installed in Yii2 error

Tags: yii2

I have a problem of my file uploading feature attached into my webapp. code is working perfectly in my localhost but not in the real server which i was uploaded already. and i was changed the directory permission to writable.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {   
       $session = Yii::$app->session;
       $user_id = $session->get('role');

        //get the instance of the uploaded file
        $imageName = $model->Fname."_".$model->Lname;

        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

        if($model->file)
        {    
          //SHA512 base password encription
          $model->password = crypt($model->repeatpassword,'$6$rounds=1212$16charactersalt');

          //save image pathe to db
          $model->image = 'uploads/profile_image/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
          $model->role = $user_id;
          $model->save();
          $model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/profile_image/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );  
        }          
        //return $this->redirect(['index']);
        return $this->goHome();
    }
```

[image: Login form]

[image: After submitting the form]

Comment: add `'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false,` in model.

Comment: model where ? you mean my database model class ?

Comment: Are you using windows operating system ?

Comment: no this is a linux server

Comment: Can you have access of php.ini file ?

Answer (score 5):

I think there is not any issue in your Yii2 code.
It may be an issue of PHP configuration.

**File Info** extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0

Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in php.ini to enable this extension.

Please visit below link for more details.

http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php

Comment: my coding working perfectly in my local server (XAMPP). i uploaded my files to real server then this error was arrived

Comment: Yeah.I have already told you that thee is not any issue in your code.
It's an issue of PHP configuration (php.ini).

Answer (score 4):

You need just uncomment in your php.ini this line:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```